# Удаление последней колонки таблицы python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

делаю приложение, которое автоматизирует генерацию учебных планов на кафедре в качестве курсового по Python. Возникла проблема - не могу удалить колонку из таблицы. Пользуюсь библиотекой `python-docx`. Поиски в интернете не привели ни к чему - код либо не запускается, либо теряется форматирование таблицы. Вот так выглядит изначально:[image]   А после срабатывания кода, вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите кодом или советом, просто к библиотеке `python-docx` нормальной документации нет, подсказок по доступным методам тоже нет, а в python я новичок
Заранее спасибо за помощь